# I finally made my add function in linked list but cant use in main. :(

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, malloc

I finally made my func but can't use it in my main.  The compiler errors with:

> > cannot convert `Node' to`Node*' for argument `1' to`void add(Node*, Node*)'

Can somebody help me resolve the error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;   
    struct Node *next;  
};
void add(Node* node, Node* newNode);
int main()
{ 
    struct Node *llist;
    struct Node *newNode;
    newNode->data = 13;
    llist = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    llist->data = 10;
    llist->next = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    llist->next->data = 15;
    llist->next->next = NULL;
    add(llist,newNode);
    printf("test\n");
    struct Node *cursor = llist;
    while (cursor != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", cursor->data);          
        cursor = cursor->next;
    } 
    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}            
void add(Node* insertafter, Node* newNode)
{
     newNode->next = insertafter->next;
     insertafter->next = newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `void add(struct Node* node, struct Node* newNode);`.

**OR**:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;   
    struct Node *next;  
}Node;
```

Also, please note that you asign values to fields of `newNode` which is a pointer, before allocating space for the actual struct:

```
newNode = malloc(sizeof(stuct Node));
```

And one more thing - if this is C and not C++, you should remove `using namespace std;`

Comment: ALso if this is C you dont need `#include <iostream>` since that's a c++ header.

Comment: yes i know that iostream is c++ but sometimes i use cout and cin too :)

Comment: Then your question should be tagged c++.

Comment: if you are going to use c++ then wn should start using pass by reference too